# Prevent dropdown on triggering upon click

Tags: jquery, html

I changed the functionality of the dropdown to be hover instead of on click, I have used the following script to achieve it.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').addClass('d-block');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('d-block');
    }
}, ".dropdown");
```

It's working fine, however, If I click on the dropdown and remove the mouse, the dropdown remains open because the clicked on it is triggered. So I tried to use the stopPropagation but I'm still able to click the dropdown.

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can try and play using this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The actual result I want is to remove the clicked functionality of the dropdown and change totally to hover only.

Answer (score 0):

After looking in more details about how Bootstraps dropdown work, I found out that removing the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute prevents the button from triggering the dropdown.

This way, only your mouse events should now control the display of the dropdown while clicking on the dropdown will not trigger it.

Comment: I think I see the issue. Because your page has Bootstrap's scripts, the handler has already been defined. If you want to override this, you'll need to get a reference to the element and unbind any existing handler.

You can do this with JQuery's `unbind` (I.e. `$(".dropdown").unbind(""click)` )
After you unbind, you can then set your handler

Comment: I've tried the unbind method but still it's not working. Is it working on your side? Using my given example?